# Axios get CORS error when I added custom headers and Authorization header also

Tags: webpack, axios, cors, webpack-dev-server

I started development mode in Next.js 12. Frontend was started on localhost:3000, backend on another port and it was with a docker, nginx and php. All works well, but when I don't set headers in request. When I added custom header or Authorization header - it crashed by CORS policy.

I added all CORS policy with a signment *. I stuck with this issue already 3 days.

To reproduce:

```
const response = axios.get('https://api.publicapis.org/entries', {
                    headers: {
                        'X-Custom-Header': 'foobar'
                    },
                    params: data,
                }).then(res => {
                    console.log(res);
                })
```

Screenshot:

https://disk.yandex.ru/i/YmPDH6pEdfem6A

Video:

https://disk.yandex.ru/i/lWaDD8WQ9s90Yw

Comment: uhm what is in the data variable?? can't very well reproduce this without

Comment: are you sure you have permission from the api to use it?

Comment: also why are you setting a custom header? it might just be the API doesn't allow it

Comment: data value is not necessary. You can delete it

Comment: I can reproduce it now, but the question remains: why do you need the custom header? in addition, the server decides how it handles your request and they deny it it seems with the custom header. You cannot change *their* server settings

Comment: You can reproduce it by send your request on your server  (url). You`ll get the same thing. This is just example, because I do it locally.
You can just install React package and do it with your own server and main thing is sent request with headers. You'll get the same.

Comment: if you are using your own server, please show us the server code then, and the exact call you make to it (e.g. axios.get(localhost etc)

Comment: I'll create a video

Comment: video: https://disk.yandex.ru/i/lWaDD8WQ9s90Yw

Comment: please add it in code to your question

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get the error in the browser is that CORS is a method to *restrict browsers*. Servers respond however they want to, unrestricted, unless programmed to specifically look at the Origin header.

In response to the pre-flight try using these headers:

- `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://your.domain` (don't use *, this doesn't work with credentials)
- `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true`
- `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization` (or whichever other custom headers you add)
- `Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST` (or whichever method you want to use)

Comment: Your adviсes don't work. It`s seems that headers allowed only from one domain to the same domain.

Comment: If the main site is domain A and you want to access domain B, then it's the domain B which needs to allow requests from domain A. If in your case domain B is https://api.publicapis.org, i.e something that you have no control over, then what you want to achieve might be impossible.

Comment: It might be to test CORS with two separate domains served from localhost, where you have full control.

Comment: look at video above, I do it all on localhost

Comment: But you are still accessing https://api.litosh-web.ru, which doesn't run on localhost. If you don't control that site then it maybe be impossible to access it with plain CORS, so the solution will be even more complicated (you could proxy the requests to a server though, which wouldn't impose any CORS restrictions at all).

Comment: If you look the video more carefully you`ll notice that at the end of video I do it locally

Comment: It would help if you add request and response headers into the question as text. I do see from the video I see that api.litosh-web.ru is indeed localhost, but then also in the browser you never open (perhaps I missed it?) the response headers themselves. I.e the video is hard to consume for people, better include all headers in the question.

Answer (score 0):

It causes by sent request on another submdomain/domain. Now I just send it to the same domain.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).